# AirDrop fails to transfer files from MacBook Pro to iPhone

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, bluetooth, sharing, airdrop

I am unable to transfer a music file from my MacBook Pro (2015 model A 1398) to my iPhone 5s. Here are the messages shown on both the MacBook Pro and the iPhone:

**macOS**:

[image]

**iOS**:

[image]

I have turned on Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. Both devices (iPhone and MacBook Pro) are able to detect each other through AirDrop. But when I attempt to transfer the file from MacBook Pro to iPhone by clicking on the iPhone, it shows failed.

There is no problem transferring files (images, music) using AirDrop from iPhone to MacBook Pro.

How to resolve this one-way failure issue?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are attempting to copy audio files from MacBook Pro to iPhone using AirDrop. It is not possible to transfer audio files this way. The way to get audio files from MacBook Pro to iPhone is to sync them via iTunes.

Using AirDrop, you can transfer photos, videos, locations, to an iOS devices or share a URL to open in iOS Safari. For more details, please refer to the Apple Support article, [Use AirDrop to send content from your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203106).

However, it is possible to transfer an audio or any other type of file without restriction from one Mac to another using AirDrop.